# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass the value of a dynamically generate URL to a javascript function

```
htmlstr += '<li class="class_name"><a  href="javascript:void(0)"' + 'onclick="javascript_name(' + url_fullimage + ')"' + '><img class="photos_class" src="photo1.jpeg" alt="thumbnail" /></a></li>'
```

The url_fullimage has a value - http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/7ukYJKDRVH0kEgnTIhqwR20GxsXf_t2_rqQDHN1n8-5x9mu1dDomTjJZMUWb6oHlVUurh-o3m_DI8ZMXU5C86yanWGg_XQ81

When I click on the image, I get a 
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

error.
I have researched various places. I am very sure the problem is with the value of the URL passed in a variable. For instance, if the variable had a value of say "sample" (instead of the URL) the function is called correctly.

Should I "escape" the special char in the URL? How do I do this, since it is dynamically generated in a variable?

I have spent 2 days on this...

Comment: We'd need to see more of your code.

Comment: Your url_fullimage  might contain a double quote. What is the value of url_fullimage ?

Comment: I have posted the value of the URL in my question Jaya

Comment: You should really be binding your events in JavaScript instead of using `onclick` attributes.  Doing it that way would make this so much easier for you and prevent issues like this.

Comment: P.S. You probably need to do: `'onclick="javascript_name(\'' + url_fullimage + '\')"'`

Comment: @ShotgunNinja - what else do you need from my code. Please let me know and I will post it.

Comment: The event handler that calls this line would be useful.

Comment: `$.click('li.class_name a', function() { ... })` is preferable to this. jQuery isn't all bad!

Answer (score 2):

To simply answer the problem in question, you're missing quotes for the string in the click handler. Fixed:

```
htmlstr += '<li class="class_name"><a  href="javascript:void(0)"' + 'onclick="javascript_name(\'' + url_fullimage + '\')"' + '><img class="photos_class" src="photo1.jpeg" alt="thumbnail" /></a></li>'
```